# How to highlight current link in foreach loop

Tags: php, html, if-statement, foreach

I have a script that lists all the directories as links.

```
<?php
$dirs = array_filter(glob('../*'), 'is_dir');
?>

<ul style="float:left;">
<?php
foreach ($dirs as $nav) {
    echo "<li><a href='$nav'>".basename($nav)."</a></li>";
}
?>
</ul>
```

I want to highlight the current directory, or give the current link a class or id. I understand that i need if statement to accomplish this like `if(currentLink=thisLink) { // add span class somehow} else {// continue looping}` , but I am not completely sure how to do this.

What would be the correct way to implement this ?

Comment: first off you need to identify what `crrentLink` is and what `thisLink` is, ie. the values to compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to find out the current directory name you need:

```
basename(getcwd())
```

in foreach loop use this:

```
if(basename($nav) == basename(getcwd()))
{
// add span class
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right you need if condition in your loop. 
Save your current link in a variable before loop.

```
<?php
$dirs = array_filter(glob('../*'), 'is_dir');
?>

<ul style="float:left;">
<?php
$currentlink='abc';
foreach ($dirs as $nav) {
     if($nav==$currentlink)
         $class='current';
     else
         $class='';
     echo "<li><a class='$class' href='$nav'>".basename($nav)."</a></li>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the variables to compair, syntax wise you want to do something like this

```
<?php
    foreach ($dirs as $nav){
         $class = '';
         if( $currentLink == $thisLink ) { 
              $class = 'class="highlight"';
         }
         echo '<li><a href="'.$nav.'" '.$class.' >'.basename($nav).'</a></li>';
   }
?>
```

You can look in `$_SERVER` to get the current url in the browser and use some of that and the basename to fill those variables in.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get current link. Store as $current_link

```
<?php
$dirs = array_filter(glob('../*'), 'is_dir');
$current_dir = 'store current directory here';
?>

<ul style="float:left;">

<?php
foreach ($dirs as $nav) {
    if($nav == $current_dir) {
        $class_name = 'active';
    }
    else {
        $class = '';
    }
    echo "<li class='$class'><a href='$nav'>".basename($nav)."</a></li>";
}
?>
</ul>
```

Hope it will works.